# Detect numbers or letters with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use an if-statement to run code only if the user types in a letter or a number.

I could use

```js
if (event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 50 || ...) {
  // run code
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe some keycodes don't work in all web browsers?

Comment: Just adding in a comment that `keycode` and `which` are deprecated and its suggested to use `KeyboardEvent.key`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you want to check a range of letters you can use greater than and less than:

```
if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
  alert('input was 0-9');
}
if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
  alert('input was a-z');
}
```

For a more dynamic check, use a regular expression:

```
const input = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);

if (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(input)) {
  alert('input was a letter, number, hyphen, underscore or space');
}
```

See the [MDC documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.keyCode) for the `keyCode` property, which explains the difference between that and the `which` property and which events they apply to.

Comment: how do i check a 'backspace' with the dynamic check?

Comment: Note that this has to be done in the `keypress` event rather than the `keydown` event.

Comment: Be aware that oddly, `String.fromCharCode` can turn non-typeable keys into characters. For example when I press the left command key on my mac I get "[" and for the right I get "]".

Comment: @chaiguy: yes, as @TimDown said, you're better off using it in conjunction with the `keypress` event, which doesn't fire (in most browsers) for most non-input keys.

Comment: Don't forget the numeric keypad: **(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)** =P

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena: that's not necessary when you're capturing the `onkeypress` event :-P (Tim kindly pointed that out in comment #2)

Comment: @AndyE MDC Docs state that `keyCode` property is deprecated & should not be used.. what would be the work around for this?

Comment: @techie_28: `keyCode` and `which` are _both_ deprecated but it won't be going away as it's required for web compatibility.  [`event.key`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key) is the future but has poor support at the minute.  I generally use `key` these days with a fallback of mapping `keyCode` to `key` values, but you can live without fear of `keyCode` going away for a long time to come.

Comment: @AndyE thanks.. the MDC Doc is warning strongly against its use so I was bit concerned.

Comment: @AndyE I think `(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)` should also be included for the NumLock keys?

Comment: @techie_28: that depends entirely on the event.  I'd recommend handling _keypress_ only if you can get away with it, then numpad keys have the same `keyCode`.

Comment: F5 has charCode 116, and String.fromCharCode(116) gives 't'. Happy programming XD

Comment: This answer is **deprecated** nowdays. See @Gibolt answer

Comment: Not sure why it is deprecated if it is the only version that works with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 46):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS!

*No number codes* anymore. You can check `key` directly.

```
const key = event.key.toLowerCase();

if (key.length !== 1) {
  return;
}

const isLetter = (key >= 'a' && key <= 'z');
const isNumber = (key >= '0' && key <= '9');

if (isLetter || isNumber) {
  // Do something
}
```

You could also use a simple regex. `^$` ensures 1 char, `i` ignores case

```
/^[a-z0-9]$/i.test(event.key)
```

or individually:

```
const isLetter = /^[a-z]$/i.test(event.key)
const isNumber = /^[0-9]$/i.test(event.key)
```

Comment: This is wrong! `(key >= "a" && key <= "z")` will return `true` for almost anything (e.g. when key = `Insert`). Same with `/[a-z]/i.test('Insert')`

Comment: There is a `length !== 1` check you missed. Fixed the regex

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `event.key.lenght === 1` covers every letter, number, space and symbol? I've been testing key.length and found that control keys have length > 1. Still, not sure if this is a good aproach

Comment: I can't guarantee that this works for anything beyond numbers and letters, which was the original question. Some international keyboards potentially could have >1 length keys. For Control, Escape, etc. directly check the value like "Enter" instead of length

Comment: @alwin-kesler `event.key.length`

Answer (score 27):

First, if you're doing this, make sure it's in the `keypress` event, which is the only event for which you can reliably obtain information about the character the user has typed. Then I'd use the approach Andy E suggested:

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
   evt = evt || window.event;
   var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
   var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
   if (/[a-z0-9]/i.test(charStr)) {
       alert("Letter or number typed");
   }
};
```

If you want to check for backspace, I'd use the `keydown` event instead and check for a `keyCode` of 8 because several browsers (including Chrome) do not fire a `keypress` event for the backspace key.

Comment: This is a much better answer as this is probably the behavior that people are looking for.

Comment: "If you want to check for backspace, I'd use  if (charCode == 8) {...}" --- I've tried this, onkeypress doesn't fire for backspace

Comment: @TKoL: Interesting. It does fire in Firefox but not Chrome. That's changed since 2010.

Comment: @TKoL: Or has it? I'm not sure now after a bit of googling. I'd normally check something like that before asserting it though.

Comment: 'delete' doesn't fire for keypress for me on multiple platforms, including jsfiddle on chrome and Windows Store html apps

Answer (score 7):

```
if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
  // the key pressed was alphanumeric
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For numeric values:

```
function validNumeric() {
  var charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  var isNumber = charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57;

  if (isNumber) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here, 48 to 57 is the range of numeric values.

For alphabetic values:

```
function validAlphabetic() {
  var charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  var isCapitalAlphabet = charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90;
  var isSmallAlphabet = charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122;

  if (isCapitalAlphabet || isSmallAlphabet) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here, 65 to 90 is the range for capital alphabets (A-Z), and

97 to 122 is the range for small alphabets (a-z).

Answer (score 2):

As @Gibolt said, you should use `event.key`.

Because `charCode`, `keyCode` and `which` are being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#phone').on('keydown', function(e) {
  let key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;

  // 32 = space - border of visible and non visible characters - allows us to backspace and use arrows etc
  // 127 - delete
  if (key > 32 && (key < 48 || key > 58) && key !== 127) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

modified answer of @user4584103, allows us to remove characters, and navigate in input box and filter out every not number character

Answer (score 1):

To detect letters & numbers when using `<input>` or `<textarea>` you can use `input` event.

This event fires when `<input>` or `<textarea>` value changes so there is no need to worry about keys like <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, arrows etc. Even more - if you use mouse to cut part of the text the event fires as well.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('search');

element.addEventListener('input',function(e){

  console.log(element.value);

});
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can add your Html forms in the input field like this:

```html
...onkeypress ="return /[a-z .@ 0-9]/i.test(event.key)" required accesskey="4"
```

You don't need any function. This Validation works only with the `email` field. Don't use naming or number. To use number, remove email regular expression like this:

```html
...onkeypress ="return /[a-z ]/i.test(event.key)" required accesskey="4"
```

For number only:

```html
...onkeypress ="return /[0-9]/i.test(event.key)" required accesskey="4"
```

Don't forget, to add for each input fields their own value.

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="Email" class="form-control " id="EMAILADDRESS" name="EMAILADDRESS" placeholder="Email Address"   autocomplete="false" onkeypress ="return /[a-z .@ 0-9]/i.test(event.key)" required accesskey="4"/>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

number validation, works fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.TxtPhone').keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;

    // only numbers
    if (key < 48 || key > 58) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `charCode` with `onKeyPress` event:

```
if (event.charCode > 57 || event.charCode < 48) {
  itsNotANumber();
} else {
  itsANumber();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.isNumeric(value);` return type is `boolean`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  return $.isNumeric(event.keyCode);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Accept numbers or letters with JavaScript by Dynamic Process using regular expression.

Add `onkeypress` event for specific control

```
onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber(event)"
```

```js
function numOnly(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  if (/[0-9]/i.test(charStr)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function Alphanum(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  if (/[a-z0-9]/i.test(charStr)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple, but useful method to try (i needed on a keyup event, letters only),
use  console.log() to check, typeOfKey is a string so you can compare. typeOfKey is either (Digit or Key)

```
 let typeOfKey = e.code.slice(0,-1) 
  if(typeOfKey === 'Key'){
  console.log(typeOfKey)  
}
```