# Validate Users Input so that users can only enter Alphabets

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate the user input so that user can only enter alphabets.
When I implement this, I can not type any characters at all or numbers, basically the input does not work.
Any ideas please?

```js
function validateName(){
  if( /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/.exec(name)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateName()" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required> <!-- Only alphabets can be entered -->
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateName()" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required> <!-- Only alphabets can be entered -->
```

Comment: You should try and find out where that `name` variable comes from. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562719/is-variable-called-name-always-defined-in-javascript

Comment: @Sébastien  Yes that had worked. I took the variable out and it worked.

Comment: I don't think it works: you can enter numbers and special characters now, so you are still not filtering out user input.

Comment: Users can still paste invalid text via context menu and other means. Also, this approach might leave users with a bad user experience (no feedback, names with diacritical marks etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the entered key to event function and fix the `regex`.

```js
function validateName(event) {
if (/^[A-z]+$/.exec(event.key)) {
 return true;
}
return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateName(event) " placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required/> <!-- Only alphabets can be entered -->
<input type="text" onkeypress="return validateName(event) " placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required/>   <!-- Only alphabets can be entered -->
```

Comment: I am pretty new here & do not entirely understand the whole process. As @Rainman stated 'mark the answer as accepted'. Not sure how do I go about this.

Comment: Well, you should accept an answer if it satistifies your needings.  Check the below of the the answer score.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this post, which is trying to accomplish the same thing: [detect numbers or letters with jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257070/detect-numbers-or-letters-with-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Thank you everyone, as I pointed out earlier & Sebastien also rightly questioned the variable 'name' origins. It worked when I took the variable name out.